# WebRTC, Differing stream ids and formatting between chrome/FF and edge

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, microsoft-edge

I'm working on establishing a RTC connection between a Chrome/ff client and Edge client. I'm using the most up to date adapter.js shim. I have everything working without a hiccup except for the following two:

1) The call can only be initiated by the Edge user, otherwise the transfer of sdp information doesn't complete.

2) When initiated by Edge user, the full exchange happens, but remote videos can't be seen, which I think I've narrowed down to a discrepancy in stream ids between the two clients.

Chrome local streamid: "aPshOXkbsPHswpajCqzaJcLowZzSHZr6QrPD"

Edge local streamid: "89077962-9A1B-47B9-8754-7B80FAAC82DF"

Chrome remote streamid (Edge local): "89077962-9A1B-47B9-8754-7B80FAAC82DF"

Edge remote streamid (should be chrome local): "3750A59D-7E90-450A-96BB-63EED7D564C3"

So it seems that Chrome has an issue with the id of the Edge stream, and then for whatever reason Edge is interpreting the Chrome stream and/or its  id.

One ancilliary issue that I've noticed with Edge is that when the success function fires from the navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia function, the video camera starts up, but then immediately shuts down. I have to enable it afterwards through javascript and then obtain stream ids, otherwise chrome/other client won't even get correct stream information of edge's running stream.

I haven't submitted an issue on the webrtc-adapter github repo yet, I'm firstly curious if anyone has any tips on how to tackle this issue. All the browsers are fully up to date. The clients are communicating from debian wheezy and Windows 10 (pro, creator's update edition). Works fine between the two machines if any combination of chrome and firefox are used.

Comment: please file an issue with a minimal reproduction. Stream ids should not matter much.
In Edge the camera light goes off if the video is not rendered locally or sent to the remote side.

Comment: I think I agree about the stream ids, I just found out that chrome to chrome none of the ids match, but the remote ids do all have the dashed format. Strange that with Edge to Chrome the Edge id stays static across clients. Thanks for the advice :)